# One Report viewer, many reports

Tags: winforms, reporting

I am converting a application where we used a local server with SSRS for reports. Corporate has now decided that instead we will use a corporate server and Tableau and ditch SSRS. I now have 20 reports that only need to be produced locally. I have decided to produced them as RDLC reports and display\print them with Report viewer. At this point the only way I know to do this is with 20 RDLC's and 20 Report viewers Forms. I am wondering if it is possible to  have one "Report viewer form" that I can pass the RDLC I want to show. It just seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Probably try adding the Tableau tag so that you can help reach an audience that will be able to help you.